# UISplitViewController: some delegate methods not fired

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller, uisplitviewdelegate

The UISplitViewControllerDelegate shows a really weird behavior. Some of the delegate methods are not being called, but others are.

The following method gets called, so the delegate is set correctly.

```
- (BOOL)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc shouldHideViewController:(UIViewController *)vc inOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation
```

The following methods don't get called.

```
- (void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)splitController willHideViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController withBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem forPopoverController:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController
- (void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)splitController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController invalidatingBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem
```

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Is the first method returning `YES`?

Comment: Exactly, it is returning YES

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem after following a few different tutorials.  It ended up that I was setting the splitViewController.delegate appropriately in one place, but I somehow I forgot to remove it somewhere else.  So the delegate was set long enough for the ShouldHideViewController method to be fired, yet was set to a different (incorrect) delegate before the willHideViewController or willShowViewController methods were fired.